# Type 'AreaData' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: json, swift, codable

When I make a model for my JSON file, I get these two errors.

1) I got the conform error in AreaData struct

2) "`AnyObject` cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol `Decodable` because `Decodable` has static requirements" error in initialiser.

I have tried several ways but I cannot find the correct solution. How can I make a proper model for this nested/complex JSON?

Here is my JSON file. This data is nested

```
[
    {
        "ID": "01",
        "Name": "Area 01",
        "parentId": null,
        "sublevel": [
            {
                "ID": "01-01",
                "Name": "Building 01",
                "On": "",
                "Off": "",
                "parentId": "01",
                "sublevel": [
                    {
                        "ID": "01-01-01",
                        "Name": "Flat 01",
                        "On": "",
                        "Off": "",
                        "parentId": "01-01",
                        "sublevel": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": "01-02",
                "Name": "Building 02",
                "On": "01",
                "Off": "03",
                "parentId": "01",
                "sublevel": [
                    {
                        "ID": "01-02-01",
                        "Name": "Flat 01",
                        "On": "",
                        "Off": "",
                        "parentId": "01-02",
                        "sublevel": []
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": "01-02-02",
                        "Name": "Flat 02",
                        "On": "01",
                        "Off": "02",
                        "parentId": "01-02",
                        "sublevel": []
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": "01-02-03",
                        "Name": "Flat 03",
                        "On": "02",
                        "Off": "12",
                        "parentId": "01-02",
                        "sublevel": [
                            {
                                "ID": "01-02-03-01",
                                "Name": "Room 01",
                                "On": "",
                                "Off": "",
                                "parentId": "01-02-03",
                                "sublevel": []
                            },
                            {
                                "ID": "01-02-03-02",
                                "Name": "Room 02",
                                "On": "",
                                "Off": "",
                                "parentId": "01-02-03",
                                "sublevel": []
                            },
                            {
                                "ID": "01-02-03-03",
                                "Name": "Room 03",
                                "On": "02",
                                "Off": "03",
                                "parentId": "01-02-03",
                                "sublevel": []
                            },
                            {
                                "ID": "01-02-03-04",
                                "Name": "Room 04",
                                "On": "",
                                "Off": "",
                                "parentId": "01-02-03",
                                "sublevel": []
                            },
                            {
                                "ID": "01-02-03-05",
                                "Name": "Room 05",
                                "On": "01",
                                "Off": "",
                                "parentId": "01-02-03",
                                "sublevel": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": "01-02-04",
                        "Name": "Flat 04",
                        "On": "12",
                        "Off": "03",
                        "parentId": "01-02",
                        "sublevel": []
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": "01-02-05",
                        "Name": "Flat 05",
                        "On": "02",
                        "Off": "",
                        "parentId": "01-02",
                        "sublevel": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": "01-03",
                "Name": "Building 03",
                "On": "02",
                "Off": "01",
                "parentId": "01",
                "sublevel": []
            },
            {
                "ID": "01-04",
                "Name": "Building 04",
                "On": "",
                "Off": "",
                "parentId": "01",
                "sublevel": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is my model class

```
import Foundation
struct AreaData : Codable {

    let iD : String?
    let name : String?
    let parentId : AnyObject?
    let sublevel : [Sublevel]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case iD = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case parentId = "parentId"
        case sublevel = "sublevel"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        iD = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .iD)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        parentId = try values.decodeIfPresent(AnyObject.self, forKey: .parentId)
        sublevel = try values.decodeIfPresent([Sublevel].self, forKey: .sublevel)
    }

}

struct Sublevel : Codable {

    let on : String?
    let iD : String?
    let name : String?
    let off : String?
    let parentId : String?
    let sublevel : [Sublevel]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case on = "On"
        case iD = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case off = "Off"
        case parentId = "parentId"
        case sublevel = "sublevel"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        on = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .on)
        iD = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .iD)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        off = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .off)
        parentId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .parentId)
        sublevel = try values.decodeIfPresent([Sublevel].self, forKey: .sublevel)
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is due to AnyObject. Codabe doesn't support anything like Any or AnyObject. You need to specify the type explicitly.

Comment: In SubLevel parentId is a string, any reason to believe it is not the same at the top level (AreaData)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
 struct AreaDataModel: Codable {
    let id, name: String
    let parentID: String? // AnyObject can't conform to Encodable protocol .  
    let sublevel: [Sublevel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case parentID = "parentId"
        case sublevel
    }
}

// MARK: - Sublevel
struct Sublevel: Codable {
    let id, name, on, off: String
    let parentID: String
    let sublevel: [Sublevel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case on = "On"
        case off = "Off"
        case parentID = "parentId"
        case sublevel
    }
}

typealias AreaData = [AreaDataModel]
```

> I recommend [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) tool simple and fast .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to `AnyObject`. `Codabe` doesn't support anything like `Any` or `AnyObject`. You need to specify the type explicitly.

In the *JSON response* you added, the `parentId` is either `null` or `String`. So, you can use `String?` as its type, i.e

```
struct AreaData : Codable {
    let parentId : String? //here.....
    //rest of the code....
}
```

Also, there is no need to specify the `rawValue` of the `case` explitly in `enum CodingKeys` if the *property* and the *key* has an exact match. So the `CodingKeys` in `struct AreaData` must be,

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case iD = "ID"
    case name = "Name"
    case parentId, sublevel
}
```

Moreover, `init(from decoder: Decoder)` is not required. This is because you're not doing any specific parsing inside it. Direct parsing will be handled by the `Codable` itself.

So, `struct AreaData` should look like,

```
struct AreaData : Codable {
    let iD : String?
    let name : String?
    let parentId : String?
    let sublevel : [Sublevel]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case iD = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case parentId, sublevel
    }
}
```

Make similar changes to `struct Sublevel` as well.

Also, use `Codable` only if you want to both *encode and decode* the data. In case you want a single functionality i.e. either *encode or decode*, use `Encodable` or `Decodable` instead.

**Recommendation:**

Since the `AreaData` and `Sublevel` contain almost same kind of data, you can use a single `struct` to `decode` that *JSON*, i.e.

```
struct AreaData: Decodable {
    let iD : String?
    let name : String?
    let parentId : String?
    let sublevel : [AreaData]?
    let on : String?
    let off : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case iD = "ID"
        case name = "Name"
        case on = "On"
        case off = "Off"
        case parentId, sublevel
    }
}
```